# Calculating Fuse Panel Wattage

Tags: power, current-measurement, watts

I am trying to figure out how many watts my house is drawing. I used a clamp-on meter to measure the current on the hot leg of my fuse panel which showed 128.8A. I am then assuming 120V which gives me 15.456kW. However, my electric rate is 0.086/kWh meaning I would have to pay $1.32 which I know is not correct.

What step am I missing here?

Comment: "kW/hr" is not really a sensible unit. Are you trying to say that your rate is $0.086/kWh? If that's the case, then you would be paying about $1.33 per hour at that rate.

Comment: @brhans it should be kWh - my mistake

Comment: Assuming you are in the US, there are 2 hot legs plus a neutral that feed your fuse panel. Each leg to neutral is 120 volts and 240 volts between the 2 hot legs. Did you measure just one leg? In which case, you need to measure the other one to get the total power being used.

Comment: Two possibilities: the meter or your interpretation of it is incorrect or it is true and you have a heater or something consuming a significant amount of power. What does the utility meter tell you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different pieces to this puzzle, and unfortunately an instantaneous read will *not* give you the full answer.

#### 120V vs. 240V

Most homes in the US have a 240V feed on *two* hot wires, plus a neutral that is right in the middle. That gives you 120V for most things (most lighting plus most receptacles around the house for small appliances, computers, TV, chargers, lights, etc.) and 240V for a few big things (clothes dryer, HVAC, water heater, oven, cooktop, EV charging). There are some variants (e.g., a gas dryer or cooktop will use 120V, a gas water heater might not use any electricity at all, window air conditioners are often 120V). But the basic point is that you really have 240V power and you need to measure *both* legs because, thanks to the 120V usage, each leg may me using a different amount of power at a particular point it time. If they were the same (all 240V appliances, no 120V usage or exactly balanced between the two legs) then you could measure one hot wire and multiply by 240. Instead you measure *both* hot wires and multiply each one by 120.

#### Demand vs. Usage

This can be huge. At any point you get a current reading, that tells you *right now* how much power you are using. But it doesn't tell you how much you will be using tomorrow or even 5 minutes from now. Demand changes every time you turn on a light, plug in a charger, turn on a toaster or use any other electric appliance. Plus demand can change even when you do nothing at all - HVAC, refrigerator, water heater, etc. cycle on/off using a thermostat even if you aren't in the house.

A *smart meter* (which your utility may have already installed, but which you likely can't read directly, unfortunately) will actually monitor voltage, current and many other parameters all the time and constantly calculate both the demand and usage. Typical meters will record demand and usage every 15 minutes. Actually for a reasonable approximation getting average demand every 15 minutes *or* total usage every 15 minutes will give you all you need to know. Demand is measured in kW (essentially Volts x Amps, except for power factor...) and usage is measured in kWh (essentially Volts x Amps x hours, except for power factor...). In other words, if you take kW average (not peak) demand for a 15 minute period and divide by 4 you get the number of kWh used in that 15 minute period. Add up all those 15 minute periods and you have your usage for the day/month/year/etc. Multiply the total usage (in kWh) by $0.086 and you have your total cost for the day/month/year/etc.

The bottom line is that an instantaneous read is very useful for certain things but is useless for determining your electric bill. You need either a meter that can read *all the time* and remembers the information (a.k.a., a smart meter), or stand there for days on end, writing down the demand every 15 minutes or so (not recommended).

Unfortunately, due to safety/code issues (that are quite valid), residential smart meters are not a cheap thing at this time. Or rather, the utilities are putting them in at a good price, but you can't do things exactly the way they do things (for a bunch of reasons). Depending on your actual needs (determine whether the utility is billing correctly? manage your electricity use?) there may be other solutions.